# MIME type of a git repository?

Tags: git, mime-types

What is the MIME type of a Git repository?

I'd like to link it from a project web page via `<link rel="vcs" type="???" href="http://git.example.org/foo.git"/>`, but for that I need to know the MIME type of a *whole git repository*.

The first file that git fetches from the HTTP transport is `/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack`, and it has a MIME type of `application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement`. But that's not for the whole repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a guy that [proposes](http://joeyh.name/rfc/rel-vcs/) to use

```
<link rel="vcs-git" href="git://example.org/foo.git" title="foo git repository"/>
```

for that purpose.

---

It strikes me odd that someone that is also called *cweiske* has a github project called [**phorkie**](https://github.com/cweiske/phorkie#features) that exactly suggests the following:

> remote pastes can be forked (**rel="vcs-git"** and gist.github.com)

(*Markup by me*)

Did you already know the solution and want to have it confirmed?

---

**Edit:**

As OP mentions in his comment, he's searching for a different way (i.e. **not** `rel="vcs-git"`).

As far as I could tell

- [there's no official MIME-type for a git repo](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html) (as well as for other directories)
- apparently there's a need (at least it's OP's need) to define one

**So, let's get it on:**

- the [classification in categories at IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) indicates to use **application** because the others (audio, example, image, message, model, multipart, text, video) would be absolutely wrong.
- [an **`X-`** prefix is used for non standard files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Prefix_x).
- the application name would be **`git`**

So, why not use **`application/x-git`** from now on...

Comment: I'm in discussion with #microformats about *rel-vcs*, and they say that using the `type` attribute is semantically better than defining 20+ `vcs-*` relation types.